# Is possible to capture the button name in a MessageFilter function?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code and I need to know the name of a button because that button is the only one that is enabled to perform task.

```
Class MessageFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter
    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        If Form1.SavingData Then
            Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
            'Const WM_MOUSELEAVE As Integer = &H2A3
            Const WM_MOUSE_LEFT_CLICK As Integer = &H201

            Select Case m.Msg
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_MOUSE_LEFT_CLICK
                    ' Do something to indicate the user is still active.
                    Form1.SavingData = False

                    Exit Select
            End Select

            ' Returning true means that this message should stop here,
            ' we aren't actually filtering messages, so we need to return false.
        End If

        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you do not use the default Form1 instance and instead pass the form reference as a argument to the message filter's constructor.  Default form instances where added to VB to facilitate converting VB6 code to VB.Net.

If you declare your filter class like this:

```
Class MessageFilter
     Implements IMessageFilter
     Private frm As Form1
     Private targetButton As Button
     Public Sub New(frm As Form1, targetbutton As Button)
        Me.frm = frm
        Me.targetButton = targetbutton
     End Sub

    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
        Const WM_MOUSE_LEFT_CLICK As Integer = &H201

        If Me.frm.SavingData AndAlso
            m.HWnd = Me.targetButton.Handle AndAlso
            (m.Msg = WM_KEYDOWN OrElse m.Msg = WM_MOUSE_LEFT_CLICK) Then
            Me.frm.SavingData = False
        End If
        ' Returning true means that this message should stop here,
        ' we aren't actually filtering messages, so we need to return false.
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

You can apply the filter like this:

```
Private filter As MessageFilter

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    filter = New MessageFilter(Me, Me.Button2)
    Application.AddMessageFilter(filter)
End Sub
```

This allows you to specify the specific Button you want to use.  The filter checks to see if the message is to be sent to that particular Button using its `Handle` property that will be a unique value instead of using its `Name` property.